# Accessibility Issues with Changing Content that is Out of the Current View

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, wai-aria

I have a page with sections, and each section is intended to be roughly one "page". The page is responsive, and the user always sees these "blocks" or "pages" as intended (demonstrated below via horizontal lines). A request has been made to make it so that when a user changes the content on one block, it changes the content of another.

[image: Example]

The "X" blocks are a carousel of images, each with a theme (let's say "Summer", "Winter", etc.).

The content in "Y" is informational. The block by "Y" is a dropdown with the same categories as those existing in the images above, and making a selection in this dropdown will swap out the content below. There MAY be more categories in "Y" than exists in "X".

So essentially, the request is that if the user advances the carousel to a new image (e.g. from "Summer" to "Fall"), then the content in "Y" should change accordingly (same basic feature as making a selection in the dropdown menu in "Y").

My concern is that there might be some negative impact to users where accessibility is an issue, since the content that is swapping out is off-page.

Is my concern unfounded? Is there a standard for this type of situation? I'm worried that something that doesn't explicitly say that it will alter other content on the page doing so will be a bad experience.

Comment: You may be looking for the [Accessible Rich Internet Applications Guidelines](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/) from the W3C. If you post some specific code, we might be able to help you implement the WAI-ARIA guidelines. You also might want to check out the [wai-aria](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wai-aria) tag here at StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

This scenario does not have to be an accessibility issue, the keys things to check are:

- Can a (sighted) keyboard user select the carousel and/or the drop-down? Check with tab, arrows and enter).
- Can a screen reader user tell that content updates when making a selection? You might hide some text above the carousel saying "Select an option from the drop-down and the content below updates".
- Do windows screen readers update their page cache ("virtual buffer") when making a selection? (Yes if the change is activated with enter/space, otherwise you might need [this script](http://juicystudio.com/article/improving-ajax-applications-for-jaws-users.php#theupdatefunction).)

Answer (score 0):

there is a potential risk for users of assistive technologies, especially screen readers, braille devices, etc. Unless there is a mechanism in place to handle the change in the content of "Y" the user may not be aware of the change.

A possible solution would be to use aria-live on "Y". See the section on Dynamic Content Changes on WebAIM's Accessibility of Rich Internet Applications post:
http://webaim.org/techniques/aria/